# Problems using this method in another class

Tags: spring-mvc

Best of all, I am using IntelliJ 8.3 with Spring MVC, and I have a problem, my WelcomeController.java is my driver and I want to use the methods that are in CatalagFacadeImpl.java but will not let me, I do not know, please help

Note: My WelcomeController, java is in HTML-> src-> package.web-> WelcomeController.java my controller.

The view the HTML-> web-> WEB-INF -> jsp -> welcome.jsp

servlet and the HTML-> web-> WEB-INF -> dispatcher-servlet.xml

and the methods I use in my controller is in CatalogFacadeImpl

HTML -> backend -> java-src -> CATW -> src -> Spring.web -> business-> impl-> CatalogFacadeImpl.java

If anyone knows and can help me

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the folder structure in a tree format so that we can understand better. Is HTML your project name? Also its better for a beginner to learn things easily if you follow a standard folder structure. You can worry less on the build and packaging things and concentrate more on the technology (here Spring MVC).

Check [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Archetypes+List) for a list of maven archetypes and Intellij IDEA has an excellent support for Maven. Start with an archetype and add your code. If you still need any help, let us know. We will more than happy to help you.

**EDIT::**

Following up with your comment, I can image safely that you are building the war file properly and able to deploy it. So can you please post what is the error you are getting? Meaning what is meant by `not let me`??  Have you autowired/injected your `CatalagFacadeImpl` into your controller?

Comment: yes, the name of the project is HTML, and I put a picture of the structure of the project but do not let me be a new user

Comment: check if the deployed path has the compiled classes or not. I mean like in your war or exploded directory check if the WEB-INF/classes has your classes or not. They can also be as a jar in lib if you did something like that.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/imageview.php?quickkey=6ik9bead37v0shc&thumb=4, please, see this picture